# Make a Command Executable On;y By One Person discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to get my code to only work with one Discord ID. It's sending "You did it!" regardless of whether or not the user has that Discord ID.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def boop(self, ctx):
        discord.Member.id=562041484174426127
        if discord.Member.id is ctx.author.id:
            await ctx.send("You did it!")
        else:
            ctx.send("You don't have permission!")
```

Comment: `is` does not compare for equality

Comment: `discord.Member.id=562041484174426127` don't do that. Just save it in a normal variable. You are overwriting a class variable. Your ´ctx.author` is instantiated from `discord.Member`. Use `==` instead of `is`.